# How do I change the PC boot from Legacy to EFI mode when boot-repair warns me?

Tags: uefi, boot-repair

I ran boot-repair and got this warning:

> The boot of your PC is in Legacy mode. You may want to retry after changing it to EFI mode.

How do I change to EFI mode? Is this done in the BIOS?

Comment: Did you mean UEFI?

Comment: Take a look at https://answers.launchpad.net/boot-repair/+question/186958

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is done in the BIOS (UEFI firmware).
The exact way to do it depends on your firmware, but generally this is done in a menu called "`Boot options`". Here are some good examples:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI#Set_up_the_BIOS_in_EFI_or_Legacy_mode