# Error in boot repair after installing Ubuntu 14.04 alongside Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8, uefi, boot-repair

I`ve installed Ubuntu 14 in my note following instructions from some tutorials in the internet, I had to enable legacy mode to boot from pen drive. Basically, I created the following 4 partitions in an empty space in my disk:

- /
- /home
- /boot
- /swap

After finishing the installation, I didn't see any option to choose the SO, instead Windows starts automatically. As recommede fot the many tutorials available in the internet I performed [boot repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair), but after have done the Recomended repair, it appears a pop up with an error message and a text file. The error message says:

```
An error occurred during the repair.

A new file (~/Boot-Info_2014-05-08__11h39.txt) will open in your text viewer.

In case you still experience boot problem, indicate its content to: boot.repair@gmail.com

You can now reboot your computer.


You may want to retry after deactivating the [Backup and rename Windows EFI files] option.

The boot of your PC is in Legacy mode. You may want to retry after changing it to EFI mode.
```

The text file is this:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/d004da42g6adv19/Boot-Info_2014-05-08__11h39.txt

My pc configuration

- Dell inspiron 14z
- Core i5
- 8GB DDR3
- 500GB / 32 GB Sata
- Windows 8.1

Comment: Take a look at http://askubuntu.com/questions/366826/how-change-to-efi-mode

Comment: I installed again and now it works. I follow steps at this answer: http://askubuntu.com/a/228069/216489